# Mapping a layout to drawable directories in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-drawable, android-studio-3.0

I've created 'drawable directories' by density and also 'layout directories' by screen size in res directory. 
The drawable directories have images in it.

[image: These are the directories]

I need to know how a 'layout' find its corresponding drawable directory from the 'drawable directories'.

Eg. 'layout-large' maps to which one of these - drawable-mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you request a resource for which you provide alternatives, Android selects which alternative resource to use at runtime, depending on the current device configuration.

See the flow chart:

[image: Flow chart]

https://developer.android.com/images/resources/res-selection-flowchart.png

Please refer to the official documentation here ['How Android finds the best-matching resource.'](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch)

Answer (score 0):

You can find tables by these links in Android developer guide.

1. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities
2. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

In first link you can see what drawables corresponds to what dpi's, second link - dp to 'small', 'large', etc ratio.

Also drawable-mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi - it is about dpi, but layout-large,-small, medium, etc. are about actual screen size. So in small screen phone, but with high dpi it could pick layout from layout-medium, but drawables from drawable-xhdpi